# Finding the nth term of 1, 6, 24, 76,212,....

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

What different methods of recursion can I use to find the nth term of this recursion? This should be simple but I don't know what I'm missing. Could you demonstrate the method?

$n(0)= 1$, $n(1)= 6$, $n(2)= 24$, $n(3)= 76$, $n(4)= 212$ $...$

$Recurrence: $

$$w_0 = 1$$
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, w_{n+1} = w_n +4 $$
$$ z_0 = w_0$$
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, z_{n+1} = z_n + (w_{n+1})  2^n$$

$$z_0 = w_0 = 1$$
$$z_1 = z_{0+1} = z_0 + (w_0+_1)2^0 = 1 + ((1+(1)4)2^0 = 6$$
$$z_2 = z_{1+1} = z_1 + (w_1+_1)2^1 = (1 + ((1+(1)4)2^0) + (1+(2)4) 2^1 = 24$$
$$z_3 = z_{2+1} = z_2 + (w_2+_1)2^2 = ((1 + ((1+(1)4)2^0) + (1+(2)4) 2^1) + (1+(3)4) 2^2 = 76 $$
I tried this but it does not seem to match my values.

$$1 + ((1+(1)4)2^0 + (1+(2)4) 2^1..... $$
$$z_n = 1 + ((1+(n-1)4)2^{n-2}) + (1+(n)4) 2^{n-1} $$

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get your recurrences from?  Your lines starting $z_1=z_{0+1}$ and so on do not make sense. What is $x$?

Comment: There is no general way to find the rule from a finite set of numbers.  You can find many sequences on this site with comments saying that the next number can be anything.  I believe problems like this can be solved sometimes, but the stated rule should convince observers that it is the correct one.  I don't see a nice rule here, but there may be one.  [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C6%2C24%2C76%2C212&language=english&go=Search) does not know the sequence.

Comment: Hello. Sorry. I've fixed my typo. "x" is actually "z"

Comment: Your recurrence does match $z_4=212$.  After that I get $548,1348,3204,7428,16900, 37892\dots $

Comment: But the nth term $z_n$ is wrong. This is what I'm trying to find. Sorry if my question was not clear enough

Comment: Wolfram gives me this: $z_n = 1 + 2^n(4n-3) + 3$ and it works but I'm really trying to understand this with different methods. I don't understand how wolfram got that recurrence so i feel it doesn't do anything to my learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite clearly $w_n=1+4n$.
Then $$\begin{align} z_n&=z_0+\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k-1}w_{k}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k-1}+4\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k-1}k\\
&=2^n\hphantom{+\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k-1}}+4\cdot((n-1)\cdot2^n+1)\\
&=(4n-3)\cdot 2^{n}+4\end{align}$$

Indeed, this matches the recursion
$$ z_0=(4\cdot 0-3)\cdot 2^0+4=1$$
and
$$ z_{n-1}-z_n=(4(n+1)-3)2^{n+1}-(4n-3)2^n=(4n+5)2^n=w_{n+1}2^n$$

Comment: Thanks for the input. Simple and easy to follow! If you don't mind, i will wait for other user inputs. I'd love to see others way to solve this problem.

Comment: Hagen, what would be the $S_n$ (the sum of n terms) of $(4n-3)*2^n+4$ ? I've accepted your answer by the way. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your method. if you suspect a degree two recurrence with an extra constant term, try
$$ x_{n+2} = A x_{n+1} + B x_n + C  $$
giving
$$ 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
6 & 1 & 1 \\
24 & 6 & 1 \\
76 & 24 & 1 
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
A \\
B \\
C 
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
24 \\
76 \\
212 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which gives
$$ A = 4, B = -4, C = 4.  $$
This gives Ross Millikan's sequence.

If the guess about type and degree of recurrence is correct, 
$$ x_{n+2} = 4 x_{n+1} -4 x_n + 4.  $$
Characteristic 
$$ \lambda^2 - 4 \lambda + 4 = (\lambda - 2)^2 $$ is promising, owing to the repeat value, which tells us to expect $n 2^n$ as part of this. It is not difficult to finish this, see if it is realistic (it is). It gives, with $n \geq 1,$
$$  x_n = (4n-7) 2^{n-1} + 4.  $$
I may have been looking at the wrong spot in Hagen's answer, since my
$$ x_{n+1} = (4n-3) 2^n + 4 $$
which Hagen has in the middle somewhere.

There is a brief description of a method for this type of problem in Conway and Guy, *The Book of Numbers*. I believe I copied a few pages years ago, but did not make a pdf. Found a book review: it is in Chapter 3, and called the Number Wall method. Not sure whether it applies to problems with extra constant in the recursion. With no extra constant, this method has one advantage: you do not need to guess the degree ahead of time, the method tells you.I dimly recall that they had a hybrid method that included finite differences, which would solve this problem.

Comment: Will, thanks for the input :) looks great